# Open WKWebView links for other websites in Safari

Tags: ios, swift, webview, safari, wkwebview

I have an app that has a wkwebview. What I need help with is when a user clicks on a link inside the webview, it opens up in Safari. But, if they click on a link with the same domain, it opens in the webview.

For example. If the webview opens up apple.com and a user click on a link that opens up apple.com/iphone I want it to open inside the webview. But, if they click on a link that opens google.com, I want it to open in the safari app. Can you give me some code so I can implement this?

(this is an iOS app using swift 3)

Answer (score 16):

In your `WKNavigationDelegate` implement `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)`. There you can check if the host of the selected link is the same like in your initial request. If not, you open the link via `UIApplication.shared.open(url)` and execute the decision handler with `.cancel` - so the link does not load in your web view. Otherwise just allow...

Quick and dirty version would be (Swift 4):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
  if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
    if let url = navigationAction.request.url, 
       originalHost != url.host, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(url)
      decisionHandler(.cancel)
    } else {
      decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
  } else {
    decisionHandler(.allow)
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a couple years old, but this just saved my life.  Thanks, @orschaef !

Comment: I am happy this also helps after this time :)